# Linkedin API v2 r_basicprofile

Tags: linkedin-api

Correct me if am wrong, but i assume the permissions listed under the **Auth** section of the app(i.e. linked-in developer app) are the ones that your app is capable of  accessing provided the intended user grants it permission via **3-legged member permission**

The problem I'm having is even after placing **r_basicprofile** in the scope and the user grants permission (i.e. access_token is aquired), when i make a GET request to **https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))** i get a response of [status: 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APMSN.png). what do i need to do to have access to **r_basicprofile** PS with **r_liteprofile** it works fine but i need basic profile because of the fields i need to access like headline. i would grateful if the code example solutions are in C# but any other language is alright

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Base on [this](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) for social login flow our apps will get r_liteprofile permission only.